# installing silverstripe shows no styling

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am trying to install silverstripe, downloaded the zip file, unzipped and copied all the files into the root of a folder in MAMP.
When I go to the root location in the url, in goes to install.php, but shows no styling whatsoever. But in the console no issues.

In this way I can't even install silverstripe because it isn't doing anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this the same issue? https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/7926

Answer (score 1):

SS 4.1 now uses a sub folder called public as root for your site. You will need to change the Document root to the public folder, and then move some files and folders into the public folder as described in the install docs.
htaccess
assets - folder
resources - folder
index
install
web.config
favicon
install-frameworkmissing

Most important run the following in composer
`composer vendor-expose`